# Hanfire skips first job execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cron, scheduled-tasks, hangfire

So I'm using Hangfire schedule jobs that send out reminders to users. Whenever I set the Job to run every monday for example at 14h00. If I do this in the morning say at 09h00. The first execution, should go off at 14h00. Problem is what seems to be happening is when I look in the dashboard it says Next execution is in 7 days.

Heres the code :

```
public class ReminderTimeService : IReminderTimeService

{
            private readonly IRecurringJobManager _recurringJobClient;

            public ReminderTimeService(
                 IRecurringJobManager recurringJobClient)
            {
                _recurringJobClient = recurringJobClient;
            }                    


            public void ScheduleJobs(List<ReminderTime> reminderTimeList)
            {
                  foreach (var reminder in reminderTimeList)
                  {
                        _recurringJobClient.AddOrUpdate<IProactiveMessageService>(
                                // Job Id
                                $"send-status-set-reminder-{reminder.Day.Substring(0, 3)}- 
                                {reminder.StartTime.Split(":")[0]}-{reminder.StartTime.Split(":")[1]}",
                                // Service to run work
                                c => c.SendStatusSetReminder(),
                                // Repeat weekly
                                GetWeekCronExpression(reminder.Day, reminder.StartTime),
                                // Use local time
                                TimeZoneInfo.Local);
                  }
           private DayOfWeek GetDayOfTheWeek(string day)
           {
            switch (day)
            {
                case "Monday":
                    return DayOfWeek.Monday;

                case "Tuesday":
                    return DayOfWeek.Tuesday;

                case "Wednesday":
                    return DayOfWeek.Wednesday;

                case "Thursday":
                    return DayOfWeek.Thursday;

                case "Friday":
                    return DayOfWeek.Friday;

                default:
                    return DayOfWeek.Monday;
            }
        }

        private string GetWeekCronExpression(string day, string time)
        {
            var hour = Convert.ToInt16(time.Split(":")[0]);
            var minute = Convert.ToInt16(time.Split(":")[1]);
            var weekStartExp = Cron.Weekly(GetDayOfTheWeek(day), hour, minute);

            return weekStartExp;
        }
}



    }
```

My guess is theres something I'm fundamentally not understanding or theres a bug with Hangfire.
In any case I'm happy to just get a work around.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a timezone problem and your `hour:minute` pair is slightly in the past. I just created a recurring job with manual parameters of `Cron.Weekly()` and in the dashboard it says, it will be perform in two hours (as expected).

Maybe you should hover over the string `In 7 days` on the dashboard, then you'll see the exact time. Check if it is your expected time and check with the debugger what comes within the `StartTime` property in your reminder object.

If all of these don't help, would be my last rescue to also add an ordinary job by calling `jobClient.Enqueue()` with the desired time.